# Script para Leitura de WebService

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, funções

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Estou tentando fazer esse código funcionar, porém no trecho:

```
success: function(retorno) {
                   If(retorno[0].erro){
                       $("h2").html(retorno[0].erro);
                   }
```

está ocorrendo um erro, e não consigo identificar o que está faltando.
A mensagem que o debuge apresenta é

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

1. // Capturando os dados do Banco de Dados

   ```
   function carregarItens(){    
   var itens = "", url = "../dados/dados.php";       
              //Captura Dados Usando Método AJAX do jQuery
              $.ajax({
              url: url, // url que puxa os dados
                      cache: false, // para os dados nao ficaram em cache
                      type :'GET',
                      dataType: "json", // Fundamental para ler como objeto compartilhado, e nao como um texto ou html comum
                      beforeSend: function() {
                      $("h2").html("Carregando..."); // Mostra informacao carregando
                      },

                      error: function() {
                      $("h2").html("Há um problema com a fonte de dados.");
                      },

                      success: function(retorno) {
                      If(retorno[0].erro){
                          $("h2").html(retorno[0].erro);
                      }                
                      else{
                      // laço para criar linhas da tabela
                      for (var i = 0; i < retorno.length; i++){
                      itens += "<tr>";
                              itens += "<td>" + retorno[i].id_cliente + "</td>";
                              itens += "<td>" + retorno[i].ds_cliente + "</td>";
                              itens += "<td>" + retorno[i].exercicio_vigente + "</td>";
                              itens += "<td>" + retorno[i].cnpj + "</td>";
                              itens += "</tr>";
                      }
                      //Preenchendo Tabela
                      $("$minhaTabela tbody").html(itens);
                              //Limpando Status Carregando
                              $("h2").html("Carregado");
                      }
                      }              

              });
              }
   ```

Comment: Qual o erro? Qual a Linha?

Comment: success: function(retorno) {
                   If(retorno[0].erro){
                       $("h2").html(retorno[0].erro);
                   }                
está ocorrendo um erro, e não consigo identificar o que está faltando. A mensagem que o debuge apresenta é

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: Já tentou colocar o if com letra minúscula?

Answer (score -1):

O if do trecho que captura os dados do banco de dados, esta com "i" Maiúsculo, inclusive a área de código do stack identifica o If como classe.